# QTP with Google Map

Tags: google-maps, qtp

I am working on Web Application that uses Google map. I need to verify balloons present on map. After some Google, i came across this link   [Automating Google Earth](http://www.advancedqtp.com/2009/12/automating-google-earth/#) .But this isn't helped lot.Does anybody has idea to work with maps in QTP?

I want to test this in IE8. When clicked on balloons, description is displayed.Need to test this description.Image for info [image: Balloons Description]

Any help ?

Comment: The "Automating Google Earth" link leads to a "nout found" page.

Comment: @TheBlastOne http://www.advancedqtp.com/automating-google-earth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be browser specific (and I'm sure it will change with changes in Google Maps) but I see in firefox that when there's a balloon then `area` and `map` elements are added to the DOM. You can create a `WebElement` with this *html tag* and see if it exists.

---

I don't really understand what problem you're facing. I can easily learn the `DIV` element which hosts a Wikipedia bubble and the elements under it with QTP.

Comment: @ Motti -Thanks for answer. I have updated Question.I guess IE DOM is not helpful for this

Comment: I have done some more research, facts are website uses Google Map API. DIV displayed in pic shows WebElement when spied from QTP. All the content - Picture, Links & Text present shows as WebElement Only. So am not getting how to test them all.

Answer (score 0):

you can try html dom if it is java application by using getElementById method from html dom ,
open firebug check the element of the pointer and get the id from it. use the id in getElementById method.
or

```
check this
Sub PostGPSLocation 
  Call Mobile.SetCurrent("Nexus 7") 
  ' Obtain location data
  Longt = Mobile.Device.GPS.Location.Longitude
  Lat = Mobile.Device.GPS.Location.Latitude
  ' Output the location data
  Call Log.Message("The device location is:")
  Call Log.Message("Longitude: "&Longt)
  Call Log.Message("Latitude: "&Lat)
  Call Log.Message("Altitude: "&Mobile.Device.GPS.Location.Altitude)
  Call Log.Message("Accuracy: "&Mobile.Device.GPS.Location.Accuracy)
```

' Open Google Maps in the browser and pass the coordinates as URL parameters
  Call Browsers.Item(Browsers.btIExplorer).Run("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"&Lat&","&Longt)
End Sub